# Webview disappears after clicking content

Tags: android, android-webview

Webview content disappears after clicking content in webview.

```
    <WebView
      android:id="@+id/squadWebView1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    webviewSquad1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webviewSquad1.loadDataWithBaseURL("", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue()), "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
    webviewSquad1.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

I have two webview one is misbehaving like this.

Comment: @JamesZ well, but people putting down votes for better questions too.

Comment: So... that's why you don't care to write a better question?

Comment: @JamesZ lol, always care about that.

Comment: @JamesZ These mistakes are i done earlier days. Now i am good. Hope you understood.

Comment: Well, looking at this question, is that really the only combination when this happens? Have you tried what happens if you remove anything from your code? Do the contents that you're loading have any affect? That's what I meant with a better question

Comment: @JamesZ Isuue has been resolved after found content hyperlink was malformed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved an issue after i corrected malformed hyperlinks in response. Beauty was that content loaded as expected.